# Intent.ACTION_VIEW does not allow edit in gallery app

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I have an app which wants to view an image in the gallery app.
I use this code to view it:

```
File cachedImage = cache.getFile(image.getImageUrl());
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(cachedImage), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works except when I click the edit setting here:

[image]

and I get the no apps can perform this action message:

[image]

Is there some way to make this work? Do I need to pass additional extras? I know the Gmail app is able to view an image attachment in the gallery and the edit function works. This is on JellyBean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way to make this work?

Install an app that can edit pictures. Your screenshots appear to be of the Gallery app, which is presumably trying to use `ACTION_EDIT` to start an activity to edit the picture, and there is no such activity available.

Comment: The Gallery app (on JB) can edit pictures when called via an intent I think - at least the Gmail app manages it somehow. I don't want to call ACTION_EDIT directly as the use case is to view it first.

Comment: @timothyjc: Install the AppXplore app on your device and examine the manifest for the Gallery, to see what their `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_EDIT` looks like.

Comment: I am not trying to call the Edit Intent directly. I am calling the View Intent which then has a link to editing the image. I downloaded the source of the Gallery app and viewed the manifest, but was unable to make headway into figuring out what was missing.

Comment: <intent-filter>
    <action
     android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category
     android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
     android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
    <data
     android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/video" />
   </intent-filter>

Comment: @timothyjc: "I am not trying to call the Edit Intent directly" -- then why are you expecting users to be able to edit the picture? There are hundreds upon hundreds of image viewers. Only one of those is the AOSP Gallery app, which itself has gone through various generations. Worrying about some bug in the Gallery app (which I presume is the source of your difficulty) is not going to somehow magically cause a hundred other image viewers that lack an Edit action bar item to magically sprout one. If you want users to edit your pictures, give them an option in *your* app to do so.

Comment: Yeah - you are probably right - was just finding it a little irritating.

Comment: @timothyjc: I certainly can't argue with that. Depending on how and when they display that dialog, LogCat might have some logging messages regarding the failed attempt to launch an editing activity. If so, that warning usually has enough info about the `Intent` that was used to see what's going on (my guess: they lost track of the MIME type). That being said, it's unlikely that it is anything that you are doing wrong that is causing Gallery to misbehave.